# Getting values from Custom-Named Columns

Tags: .net, mpxj

I'm working with an MPP file that has some additional columns with names like "Text5", "Text10", etc. Obviously these are not default columns with simple access through the Task class. I've seen the Column class, but don't see a way to access specific-named Columns via the Task class.

How do I retrieve values from a Task object in columns other than the default columns?

Answer (score 1):

The Task class has a GetText(int) method that allows for retrieving fields like this. I was able to get the values I need by using task.GetText(5) for the Text5 field.

Answer (score 1):

You could use getFieldByAlias() to get value from custom-name column: 
Example: task.getFieldByAlias("Text5")

Regards,